# Heat Transfer, Water in a pot

Tags: thermodynamics, water

I have a question I've been pondering for a while. How can I determine the temperature in a pot filled with water?

I know these things:

I have a known mass of water, of mass  $m_w$

I have a pot of know material, volume, and surface area

I have the rate at which energy is put out by the eye of stove in Watts as a differentiable function of time in seconds, either  $\frac{dQ}{dt}(x,y,z)$ or $\nabla Q(x, y, z)$

I have the specific heat of water $c_w$ with units $\frac J{K \centerdot KG}$ as a continuous and differentiable function of temperature in $K$.

I know the intitial temperature in Kelvin of the water and the pot

I know the thermal conductivity of the water and the pot.

Here is where I started:

$Q = m_wc_w\Delta T$

$Q = m_wc_w(T_x - T_0)$

$\frac Q{m_cc_w}+ T_0$ = $T_x$

$T_0 + \frac Q{m_cc_w} \int^{t_x}_{t_0}{\frac {dQ}{dt}(x,y,z)dt} = T_x$

or possibly

$T_0 + \frac Q{m_cc_w} \iiint^{t_x}_{t_0}{\nabla Q(x,y,z)dt} = T_x$

What I'm stuck on how to determine the the thermal energy of the water given that heat is transfer from the eye of the stove to the pot and then to water.

Also, which expression for the rate of change of energy is more appropriate for this problem, $\frac{dQ}{dt}(x,y,z)$ or $\nabla Q(x, y, z)$?

Comment: Where did that last equation come from?

Comment: Yeah,I think the $Q$ should be removed if you're placing an integral like that over there. Is that what you mean @KyleKanos?

Comment: @Cheeku: It seems he's just doing some rearranging from line 2 to line 3, but then invents some integral in line 4. I'm not sure the justification or origin of it.

Comment: I was making a guess that if the $\frac {dQ}{dt}$ for the water in the pot and integrated with respect to time it would give me thermal energy of the water. But since this is in three dimensions since water has volume, it's probably more appropriate to say $\iiint ^{T_x}_{T_0} \nabla Q(x, y, z)dt$

Comment: I'm making a guess that it would be easier to determine the rate at which energy is given by the eye of the stove than to measure the direct the energy produced at time t, but I could be wrong